# Event Bus equivalent in iOS

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift

Heard about java 'publish-subscribe' style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly be aware of each other,  which is Event bus.It seems that using event bus we can communicate between different classes very easily with less coding needed.I know that NSNotifications in iOS also do this. NSNotification is not a replacement here.Please let me know apart form delegation pattern what is a good solution in iOS which is a good replacement for EventBus for communication between classes.?

Comment: Are you sure NSNotificationCentre isn't what you're looking for? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html

Comment: No. NSNotificationCentre uses a one to many communication. I need one to one communication at a time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With **Swift** you can use [SwiftEventBus](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus). It's *just* a nice [*wrapper* around NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) and [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue).

Register to an event:

```
SwiftEventBus.onMainThread(target, name: "someEventName") { result in
    // UI thread
    // Do something when the event occurr
}
```

Trigger an event:

```
SwiftEventBus.post("someEventName")
```

And if you need to customize it, the [source code](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus/blob/master/SwiftEventBus/SwiftEventBus.swift) is *short*, *clear* and *easy* to understand.

Comment: Hey, I'm the creator of the library, glad you guys are finding it useful :) cheers

Answer (score 6):

I think you *can* use `NSNotificationCenter` for this, I read your comment about it is one-to-many and it's true by default but you can specify from which object do you want to receive messages like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(someSelector:)
                                             name:@"MyPersonalNotification"
                                           object:someOtherObject];
```

Here you will receive the `MyPersonalNotification` in `someSelector:` only when `someOtherObject` post it. This made the communication one-to-one.

Also you can use the [Key-Value Observing API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) but I personally found it somewhat uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [tolo](https://github.com/genzeb/tolo).
The functionality is somewhat similar to an event bus and it has one big advantage over NSNotification as you don't have to unregister when deallocating (like in iOS9).